# SQLite Aggregate Sum Values

Tags: sqlite, dbeaver

When I try to aggregate the price, the returned value is truncated and cuts off significant values. For example, when I use sum() or total() to aggregate price, instead of 12,000.00 it returns 12.

I have used both sum() and total() as well as trying to cast the number as a float. The column is of type REAL.

```sql
select "Extended Price" 
from ReqData 
where "PR ID" = 11111111 
group by "PR ID";
```

This returns 12,000.00

```sql
select sum("Extended Price") 
from ReqData 
where "PR ID" = 11111111 
group by "PR ID";
```

This returns 12.

[DBeaver Output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/x480s.png)

Comment: I can't reproduce your problem. In DB Browser For SQLite both queries return 12000.0

Comment: Snapshot image added.

Comment: Do you have only 1 row with "PR ID" = 11111111 in the table?

Comment: Yes, 1 row with Extended Price 12,000.00

Comment: See my answer...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is that you inserted the column's value like:

```
12,000.00
```

This is recognized from SQLite as `TEXT` because it contains the comma.
Change the value to:

```
12000
```

or

```
12000.00
```

When a TEXT value is used to perform arithmetic operations like addition, subtraction or even comparisons, SQLite tries to convert it to numeric starting from the starting chars and if this is not possible at all it returns `0`.
So `'12a'` will be converted to `12`, `'abc'` will be converted to `0`, so in your case `'12,000.00'` is converted to `12`.

Comment: Ah, that makes sense, I had a feeling it was a data type issue but I wasn't sure how SQLite handles the types. Thanks!